# Checking for integer overflow does not work using Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working through a coding challenge where I have to reverse an integer.  If the integer has only 1 digit, I return the integer as it is.  If its less than zero, I reverse it but keep the sign intact.  I have to check for integer overflow to make sure that it is in the range `[−231,  231 − 1]`.  The following is my code:

```
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
    
    if x >=0 and x <= 9:
        return x
    
    elif x > 9 and x < (2**31):
        rever1 =  str(x)[::-1]
        return int(rever1)
    
    elif x < 0 and x > (-2**31):
        rever2 = str(x)[::-1]
        rever2 = rever2[:-1]
        rever2 = -1  * int(rever2)
        return rever2
    
    elif x <= (-2**31) or x >= (2**31):
        return 0
```

I know how to make this code shorter so the inefficiency is fine for now. I just want to know why my code fails for `1534236469`.

As much as I appreciate all help, it helps me more if you just tell me why the code fails instead of giving me a quick solve. The whole point behind these challenges is to learn so it defeats the purpose if someone just puts the answer.

Comment: What is `self`?

Comment: Could this be because the reversed integer would be greater than `2**31-1`?

Comment: @Stef, this is how Leetcode structures answers. It has to be a method of a class `Solution`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check the *input* value, rather than the return value.  The test case you give is the "problem" class: the input number is in range, but the reverse is not.

You need to check `rever1` for being in range, as well:

```
elif x > 9 and x < (2**31):
    rever1 = str(x)[::-1]
    return int(rever1)
```

Could be

```
elif x > 9 and x < (2**31):
    rever1 = str(x)[::-1]
    if rever1 < (2**31):
        return int(rever1)
    else:
        return 0
```

Since you're planning to shorten the code appropriately, I won't go into those details.